# Full-Text Seach and stemming on multilanguage column

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, stemming, wordbreaker

I have a table with a column that contains data in different languages, like that:

```
Id    Text    Language

1     name      en
2     names     en
3     имя       ru
4     nom       fr
```

I need Full-text search for this multilingual column, but FTS is known to require one language for one column.

Microsoft tutorials says that that you can convert the data into XML and define the language attribute, e.g.

```
Id                   Text   

1     <content xml:lang = "en">name</content> 
2     <content xml:lang = "en">names</content> 
3     <content xml:lang = "ru">имя</content>    
4     <content xml:lang = "fr">nom</content>
```

However, this will only work for the word breaker, not stemming, and a similar query **will not be** executed with the result `{name, names}`:

```
SELECT text
FROM [Test].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE freetext (Text , 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "name")')
```

Is it possible to do something to make stemming work?